# SQL counting days from periods

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum, having, date-arithmetic

My problem is that I want to sum periods of date from only may, but as you can see below some of events starts before first day of may and some end after last may day.

There is my code:

```
SELECT * FROM rooms p, bookings r WHERE p.id_room = r.id_room group by 
r.id_room having 
case
    WHEN (month(r.start_date) = 5 AND month(r.end_date) = 5) THEN 
    sum(datediff(r.end_date, r.start_date)) < 21
    WHEN (month(r.start_date) < 5 AND month(r.end_date) = 5) THEN 
    sum(datediff(r.end_date, '2022-05-01 12:00:00')) < 21
    WHEN (month(r.start_date) = 5 AND month(r.end_date) > 5) THEN 
    sum(datediff('2022-05-31 12:00:00', r.start_date)) < 21
END;
```

[image: 3 examples]

Edit 1

[image: 2 other options]
I will only talk about example on bottom.
E.g.
date_Start - June 3
date_end - June 15

GREATEST(date_start, '2022-05-1') returns June 3
LEAST(date_end, '2022-05-31') retruns may 31

DATEDIFF(date_end, date_start) returns -3 and it is still counted as day from may while it should be skipped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplify the `HAVING` clause by using the functions [`LEAST()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) and [`GREATEST()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest):

```
SELECT r.id_room  
FROM rooms r LEFT JOIN bookings b 
ON b.id_room = r.id_room 
AND b.end_date > '2022-05-01 12:00:00' AND b.start_date < '2022-05-31 12:00:00'
GROUP BY r.id_room 
HAVING SUM(COALESCE(DATEDIFF(
             LEAST(b.end_date, '2022-05-31 12:00:00'),
             GREATEST(b.start_date, '2022-05-01 12:00:00')
       ), 0)) < 21;
```

Also, use a proper join.

Comment: i have still little problem. There could be situation when someone start and end in totaly differenet month than my i mean e.g. start is 3 june and end is 15 june

Comment: @LLager what do you want in this case?

Comment: Wait, I'll edit my post

Comment: @LLager check my edited code.